# Linq to Objects - Left Outer Join Distinct Object Property Values to an Aggregate Count

Tags: linq, left-join, distinct, aggregate-functions

Lets say I have a generic list of the the following objects:

```
public class Supermarket
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

So using a `List<Supermarket>` which is populated with many of these objects with different values I am trying to:

1. Select the distinct `Suburb` properties from a
   superset of `Supermarket` objects contained in a `List<Supermarket>` (say this superset contains 20
   distinct Suburbs).
2. Join the Distinct List of Suburbs above to another set of aggregated and counted Suburbs obtained by a LINQ query to a different, smaller list of `List<Supermarket>`

The distinct items in my superset are:

```
"Blackheath"
"Ramsgate"
"Penrith"
"Vaucluse"
"Newtown"
```

And the results of my aggregate query are:

```
"Blackheath", 50
"Ramsgate", 30
"Penrith", 10
```

I want to join them to get

```
"Blackheath", 50
"Ramsgate", 30
"Penrith", 10
"Vaucluse", 0
"Newtown", 0
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
var results = from distinctSuburb in AllSupermarkets.Select(x => x.Suburb).Distinct()
                select new
                {
                    Suburb = distinctSuburb,
                    Count = (from item in SomeSupermarkets
                            group item by item.Suburb into aggr
                            select new
                            {
                                Suburb = aggr.Key,
                                Count = aggr.Count()
                            } into merge
                            where distinctSuburb == merge.Suburb
                            select merge.Count).DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                } into final
                select final;
```

This is the first time I have had to post on Stack Overflow as its such a great resource, but I can't seem to cobble together a solution for this.

Thanks for your time

EDIT: OK So I solved this a short while after the initial post. The only thing I was missing was chaining a call to `.ElementAtOrDefault(0)` after the call to `.DefaultIfEmpty(0)`. I also verifed that using `.First()` instead of `.DefaultIfEmpty(0)` as Ani pointed out worked, The correct query is as follows:

```
var results = from distinctSuburb in AllSupermarkets.Select(x => x.Suburb).Distinct()
                select new
                {
                    Suburb = distinctSuburb,
                    Count = (from item in SomeSupermarkets
                            group item by item.Suburb into aggr
                            select new
                            {
                                Suburb = aggr.Key,
                                Count = aggr.Count()
                            } into merge
                            where distinctSuburb == merge.Suburb
                            select merge.Count).DefaultIfEmpty(0).ElementAtOrDefault(0)
                } into final
                select final;
```

LASTLY: I ran Ani's code snippet and confirmed that it ran successfully, so **both** approaches work and solve the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand the assumed equivalence between `State` and `Suburb` (`where distinctSuburb == merge.State`), but you can fix your query adding a `.First()` after the `DefaultIfEmpty(0)` call.

But here's how I would write your query: using a `GroupJoin`:

```
var results = from distinctSuburb in AllSupermarkets.Select(x => x.Suburb).Distinct()
              join item in SomeSupermarkets 
                        on distinctSuburb equals item.Suburb
                        into suburbGroup
              select new
              {
                    Suburb = distinctSuburb,
                    Count = suburbGroup.Count()
              };
```

Comment: Thanks Ani. I solved the problem with my original approach and fixed the issue you pointed out where I mistakenly confused the State and Suburb properties.